# get text from grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
 <asp:GridView Width="700" ID="gridInboxMessage" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
    <Columns>                                
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Row" Visible="false" HeaderStyle-Width="10" HeaderText="row" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Row" />  
<asp:BoundField DataField="Title"  HeaderStyle-Width="10" HeaderText="Title" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Title" />  
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

`row` is visible=false.

How can get the text of this> `gridInboxMessage.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text` does not return value

If `row` is visible=true then by `gridInboxMessage.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text` I can get text.

Comment: you only have one column in your grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with setting display:none on that column. This is less code, only adding a css on the column you want invisible

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hiddencol
    {
        display:none;
    }

</style>

<asp:GridView Width="700" ID="gridInboxMessage" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
<columns>
    <asp:boundfield datafield="ProductID" itemstyle-cssclass="hiddencol" />
    <asp:boundfield datafield="Name" headertext="Product Name" />
    <asp:boundfield datafield="ProductNumber" headertext="Product Number" />
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the value of the column that you had set `visible=false`, because it is not rendered on the client side and it will not be available on postback. You can use a hidden field and get the value from the `hidden field` instead.

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdf" Value='<# Eval("Row")'>
                </asp:HiddenField>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: say error :Error 1 Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField' does not have a public property named 'HiddenField'. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BackSite\ControlPanelPP.aspx 527

Comment: Hidden field should be ItemTemplate, that was missing. Please get the new code from the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

once it is established whether the row of datagrid and visible for the text you can use this example.

This example is for c#

```
            string myValue = string.Empty;
        myValue = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```